# Angular 2 ag-grid: create an button and bind (click) event listener to it

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

So I am trying to add a event listener but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working, when I click on it, nothing happens.

This is my column definition:

```
{
    "headerName":"Work Instance Id",
    "field":"wrkInstId",
    "width":100,
    // cellRendererFramework:LinkComponent,
    "cellRenderer": (pars)=>{
      return '<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="viewMetricUploadData()">' + pars.node.data.wrkInstId + '</a>';
    }
},
```

### My template

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 555px;" class="ag-fresh"
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [rowdata]="gridData"  >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

### Typescript

```
viewMetricUploadData(){
    console.log('here');
}
```

How can I invoke method inside my controller ?

Comment: Your string template won't be parsed by angular

Comment: yes thats why im looking for fix

Comment: There are two great examples on the [Docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0) page of using `cellRendererFramework`. [One](https://plnkr.co/edit/J04rdB?p=info) and [Two](https://plnkr.co/edit/qmgvkW?p=info)

Comment: worked great thanks Jarod